# Sun Studio 11 for Solaris 8. Oracle site does not have it (Dead Link)

Tags: solaris, sunstudio

I need Sun Studio 11 specifically since it is the last one supported on Solaris 8.
The Oracle site simply does not have it. It seems to be a bug, and goes around in circles. i.e. Oracle site says "Sun links are dead, go here on Oracle site", and Oracle site links to the same old Sun site.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index-jsp-138519.html

And of-course the bottle-neck is Solaris 8, so if Sun Studio 12 installs and works on it. I am more than willing.

Comment: I believe it's only available for customers with support contracts going through tech support, since it's well past the End of Life of that release.

Comment: Actually, it does not appear to be that. It appears to be a bug on the site.

Comment: @KGA - can you provide the link? We need to test Sun Studio 11 for a couple of bug reports. We have a Solaris 10 machine setup, but we can't find the actual download. We are caught in a webmaster's broken site loop.